# How to iterate through angular $scope variables with a loop

Tags: angularjs, scope, angularjs-scope

I want to iterate through $scope variables with a for loop like this.
In this example the $scope object includes an object *accounts* 
inlcuding 5 objects, whose names are numbers from 1 to 5. Each of them has a name.

```
for(var i = 1; i < 5; i++){
   $('#name').val($scope.accounts.i.name);
}
```

**The problem:** *$scope.accounts.i* is *undefined* because i does not count as a varibale inside the *$scope* variable.
It counts as the letter i, so I see no chance to iterate through a scope with a for loop.
When I use  " " around the $scope variable it will just be displayed as plain html and angular is not interpreted.

Comment: so account is a array containing 5 objects of five key value pairs?

Comment: accounts is an array with 5 objects and several key value pairs. But of course every account has the same number of pairs. ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Loop through array in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Angular way to do above is

```
 $scope.accounts=[{name:"123"},{name:"124"},{name:"125"}]

            angular.forEach($scope.accounts,function(value,index){
                alert(value.name);
            })
```

Answer (score 1):

If accounts is an array, you can use the array indexer:

```
for(var i = 1; i < 5; i++){
   $('#name').val($scope.accounts[i].name);
}
```