# how to loop with out a collection in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I have a number and I want to iterate that number of times.

```
for (var _i = 0; _i < length; _i++)
```

I want to implement similar to this syntax in the html template. if i use ngFor then i will need to have a collection but I don't have collection, I just have length.

Comment: Infinite number of ways to do that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to iterate through angular $scope variables with a loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17326796/how-to-iterate-through-angular-scope-variables-with-a-loop)

Comment: It's a possible duplicate of this..http://stackoverflow.com/q/35405618/6128276

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36354325/angular-2-ngfor-using-numbers-instead-collections it seems

Answer (score 2):

You could create an array of the right size in the component and iterate on it:

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let i of arr">foo</li>
    </ul>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  arr = new Array(10);  // let's say 10 is your number
}
```

FYI, I tried declaring the array directly in the template but it doesn't work:

```html
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let i of new Array(10)">foo</li>
</ul>
```