# How to pass the java script for loop variable to ${ }?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<script >
    document.write("<table border=2 width=50%"); 
    for (var i = 0; i < ${SALE_DATA.SALE_ORDER_ITEMS_LIST.length}; i++) {  
      document.write("<tr>");
      document.write("<td>" + ${SALE_DATA.SALE_ORDER_ITEMS_LIST[i].WEIGHT} + "</td>");
      document.write("<td>" + i + "</td>");
       document.write("</tr>");
    } 
    document.write("</table>"); 
</script>
```

I am trying to pass the i in `${SALE_DATA.SALE_ORDER_ITEMS_LIST[i].WEIGHT}`
here SALE_DATA is the constant array in angular 5.
but it is giving the error like below

ERROR ReferenceError: i is not defined.
suggest me the way to pass the i value in loop

if i keep the `${SALE_DATA.SALE_ORDER_ITEMS_LIST[0].WEIGHT}`
the output is like below

thanks in advance!!
[out put](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lk05l.png)

Comment: Maybe this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17326796/how-to-iterate-through-angular-scope-variables-with-a-loop

Comment: What kind of syntax is `${}` outside of a template string? You should get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {` as an error

Answer (score 1):

you can you use template literal (``) to create a string with dynamic variables in it.

```
for (var i = 0; i < `${SALE_DATA.SALE_ORDER_ITEMS_LIST.length}`; i++) {
  console.log(i)
}
```

Above code will work fine but it's not recommended to use template literals in this manner.

> Template literals are string literals allowing embedded expressions.
>   You can use multi-line strings and string interpolation features with
>   them. They were called "template strings" in prior editions of the
>   ES2015 specification.

Comment: Yeah for (var i = 0; i < `${SALE_DATA.SALE_ORDER_ITEMS_LIST.length}`; i++) {
  console.log(i)
}  is working fine, but when we try to access i in ${SALE_DATA.SALE_ORDER_ITEMS_LIST[i].WEIGHT it producing the above error......  Thanks for the reply @ Nikx

Answer (score -2):

You may use an intenal iterator , like using forEach loop. This will allow you not taking care of how the loop works.

Something like this can do the job.

```
 ${SALE_DATA.SALE_ORDER_ITEMS_LIST}.forEach(function(curVal,i){
      document.write("<tr>");
  document.write("<td>" + curVal.WEIGHT + "</td>");
  document.write("<td>" + i + "</td>");
   document.write("</tr>");
 })
```